# retrieve sequence alignment score produced by emboss in biopython

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to retrieve the alignment score of two sequences compared using emboss in biopython. The only way that I know is to retrieve it from an output text file produced by emboss. The problem is that there will be hundreds of these files to iterate over. Is there an easier/cleaner method to retrieve the alignment score, without resorting to that? This is the main part of the code that I'm using.

```
From Bio.Emboss.Applications import StretcherCommandline
needle_cline = StretcherCommandline(asequence=,bsequence=,gapopen=,gapextend=,outfile=)
stdout, stderr = needle_cline()
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some time spent on searching for a neat solution I popped up a white flag.

However, to speed up significantly the processing of output files I did the following things:

1) I used *re* python module for handling regular expressions to extract all data needed.

2) I created a ramdisk space for the output files. The use of a ramdisk here allowed for processing and exchanging all the data in RAM memory (much faster than writing and reading the output files from a hard drive, not to mention it saves your hdd in case of processing massive number of alignments).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is one specifically for your command.

For  `Primer3CommandLine`, there is [`Primer3`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Emboss.Primer3.Primers-class.html). Make your life much easier with something like:

```
from Bio.Emboss import Primer3
inputFile = "./wherever/your/outputfileis.out"
with open(inputFile) as fileHandle:
    record = Primer3.parse(fileHandle)
    # XXX check is len>0
    primers = record.next().primers
    numPrimers = len(primers)
    # you should have access to each primer, using a for loop
    # to check how to access the data you care about. For example:
```

I would also check http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO#Sequence_Input